# How to make Python do nothing

Tags: python-3.x

So I have my code for detecting palindromes in an inputted list, if there is no palindromes the program is supposed to do nothing but in this case it prints out a new empty line. In my program I used "pass" to try and make it do nothing but my guess is that the return of the result is make it print out empty line.

```
def unos():
  lista = [int(clan) for clan in input("Unesi članove niza : ").split(',')]
  lista.reverse()
  return lista   

def obrada(lista):

    rezultat = []
    c = 0
    for i in lista:
        if i < 0:
            i = i * -1
            t = i
            rev = 0
            rev = rev * 10 + t % 10
            t = t // 10
            i = i * -1
            rezultat.append(str(i))
        else:
                t = i
                rev = 0
        while t > 0:
            rev = rev * 10 + t % 10
            t = t // 10
            if rev == i:
                c=c+1
                rezultat.append(str(i))
            else:
                pass
    return(','.join(rezultat))

def ispis(konacan):

    print(konacan)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    konacan_lista = unos()
    konacan = obrada(konacan_lista)
    ispis(konacan)
```

Comment: `pass` is only meant as a filler for Python syntax. For example, when you catch an exception and don't want to do anything with it. Without it, Python would try to consider the next line as the content. You might be looking for `break` and `continue` that stop the current loop and skip the rest of the loop and go to the next value, respectively. Another option is to use the `for... else` construct that is quite elegant in Python.
But of course, in your specific case, just checking that the result is there before printing is probably the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just make sure that the `print` instruction is not executed when you have no result (empty string):

```
def ispis(konacan):
    if konacan:
        print(konacan)
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO SO MUCH

Answer (score 0):

`print(konacan,end=' ')` should do it.

Comment: That still prints a space. You'd have to pass `end=''`...

Comment: I thought he didn't want a new line to be printed. But yes, to do nothing ```end=''``` will do it.